# how to handle `%` if it is present in a string while reading it using `fscanf()`

Tags: c, scanf

Let's say there is a file `a.txt` in which each string is a key values pair as `<key: value>`. But one constraint is that my key could contains character like `%` too. For example: as given below

```
string : INDIA
integer : 2015
ratio %: 20
integer2 : 2016
```

Now by using the `fscanf`, I want to validate each value of string present in file `a.txt`.

My sample code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char str[8];
   int arr[2];

   FILE * fp;
   int j=0;
   char *out_format[4] = {
       "string :",
       "integer :",
       "ratio %:",
       "integer2 :"
   };

   fp = fopen ("a.txt", "r");

   if (fp == NULL) {
       perror( "fopen failed for input file\n" );
       return -1;
   }

    for (j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        char c[64]={'\0'};
        strcat(c, out_format[j]);

        if (j == 0) {
           strcat(c, " %s ");
           fscanf(fp, c, str);
           printf("%s %s\n", c, str);
        }
        else {
           strcat(c, " %d ");
           fscanf(fp, c, &arr[j-1]);
           printf("%s %d\n",c, arr[j-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT I received after compilation is:

```
string : %s  INDIA
integer : %ld  2015
ratio %: %ld  0
integer2 : %ld xxxxx  // some garbage
```

This is happening due to `%` present in line `ratio %: 20` of file `a.txt`.

Please, can someone suggest here ? How to handle this, so that I can get the correct values as present in file?

Comment: It looks like `c[12]` is too small an array since `"integer2 :"` is 10 characters, and `" %s "` is another 4, so `c` should have room for 15 characters including the trailing zero.

Comment: this line: 'if (fp < 0) {' should be: 'if (fp == NULL) {' because comparing a pointer to integer is not valid.  and fopen() returns a pointer, not a number, (your compiler should have told you this.) Suggest enabling all warnings when compiling. (for gcc, at a minimum, use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: this line: 'char c[64]={};' should be: 'char c[64]={'\0'};'  because otherwise, no initialization is performed.  (your compiler should have told you this)

Comment: using printf( "Error\n"); after a call to fopen() fails is telling the user little to nothing useful.  suggest: perror( "fopen failed for input file" );  which will also print the system error message for the current value of 'errno'

Comment: ^^ Thanks, updated the sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `%%` to eascape and match a `%`. From the scanf man page :

> %
>
> Matches  a  literal  '%'.   That  is,  '%%' in the format
>   string
>           matches a single input `%' character.  No  conversion  is  done,
>           and assignment does not occur.

Manual: http://www.manpages.info/linux/scanf.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%%` to replace `%`,`%%` is stand for literal `%` in C.